# apipa ip address showing win 2008 r2 but static ip is configured.

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed win 2008 server R2 in VMware esxi and I configured static IP for that VM, but sometime I am not able to ping that VM from the network. Static IP is configured for that cm but during this problem when I issued the ipconfig command it shows apipa IP address. In that ESXI server I have two NIC configured for 2 different networks.

Comment: do you also have 2 vswitches for those 2 different networks?

Comment: Yes, i one core switch of Cisco 3850 where  VLAN 100 L3 SVI is configure and other VLAN 200 is normal L2 VLAN. From core switch trunk port connect to server rack access switch from there VLAN 100 access port is connect to ESXI server one NIC port and one more trunk from VLAN 200 in different switch and there VLAN 200 access port connect to ESXI other NIC for VALN 200.

Comment: vSwitch0 and vSwitch1...?

Comment: Do you have VMware Tools installed in the guest and are they up to date?

Comment: no VMware Tools is not installed and i used 2 NIC for 2 VLAN. Also mapped one vNIC with one physical NIC and other like the same way.

Comment: The first thing to do is to install VMware Tools in the guest. This is a known issue regarding missing or out of date VMware Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at VMware's article on the issue:
https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1028373

It's a problem with gratuitous ARP between Cisco and Microsoft.  You can work around it with a registry edit.

Go to:  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters

Create a DWORD:  ArpRetryCount

And set it to 0.

There are also changes you can make on the Cisco side, but that's beyond my knowledge.